# to get rid of warning and error: non-language object in R

Tags: r, r-s4

I am coding in R and I have a small chunk that I need to loop it over.

the part of the code looks like this:

```
sc_1$ue <- cF(sc_1, 2500, 1000, 5)
sc_2$ue <- cF(sc_2, 2500, 1000, 5)
sc_3$ue <- cF(sc_3, 2500, 1000, 5)
sc_4$ue <- cF(sc_4, 3000, 1000, 5)
```

where cF is a function I am calling. This code in its present form works without any error.

However, when I try to loop it like the following:

```
sc_list=mget(sc)
for (i in 1:5)
sc_list[i]$ue <- cF(sc_list[i], 2500, 1000, 5)
```

where sc contains sc_1 to sc_n objects.

The output is not an immediate error but a warning.

```
## Warning in sc_list[i] <- `*vtmp*`: number of items to replace is not a
## multiple of replacement length

## Warning in sc_list[i] <- `*vtmp*`: number of items to replace is not a
## multiple of replacement length

## Warning in sc_list[i] <- `*vtmp*`: number of items to replace is not a
## multiple of replacement length

## Warning in sc_list[i] <- `*vtmp*`: number of items to replace is not a
## multiple of replacement length
```

because of this following code in the program gives me an error.

How can I fix this?

What I have tried is:

```
sc_list=mget(sc)
    for (i in 1:length(paths))
      paste0("sc_",i)$ue <- cF(sc_list[i], 2500, 1000, 5)
```

This throws up an error.

```
Quitting from lines 209-217 (prototype.Rmd) 
Error in paste0("sc_", i)$use <- cF(sc_list[i], 2500, 1000,  : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
```

Edit: output of

```
 > str(sc_list)
    List of 4
     $ sc_1:Formal class 'SingleCellExperiment' [package "SingleCellExperiment"] with 10 slots
      .. ..@ int_elementMetadata:Formal class 'DataFrame' [package "S4Vectors"] with 6 slots
      .. .. .. ..@ rownames       : NULL
      .. .. .. ..@ nrows          : int 33694
      .. .. .. ..@ listData       :List of 2
      .. .. .. .. ..$ is_spike_MT: logi [1:33694] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ is_spike   : logi [1:33694] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
      .. .. .. ..@ elementType    : chr "ANY"
      .. .. .. ..@ elementMetadata: NULL
      .. .. .. ..@ metadata       : list()
      .. ..@ int_colData        :Formal class 'DataFrame' [package "S4Vectors"] with 6 slots
      .. .. .. ..@ rownames       : NULL
      .. .. .. ..@ nrows          : int 5586
      .. .. .. ..@ listData       : Named list()
      .. .. .. ..@ elementType    : chr "ANY"
      .. .. .. ..@ elementMetadata: NULL
      .. .. .. ..@ metadata       : list()
      .. ..@ int_metadata       :List of 2
      .. .. ..$ version    :Classes 'package_version', 'numeric_version'  hidden list of 1
      .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:3] 1 0 0
      .. .. ..$ spike_names: chr "MT"
      .. ..@ reducedDims        :Formal class 'SimpleList' [package "S4Vectors"] with 4 slots
      .. .. .. ..@ listData       : list()
      .. .. .. ..@ elementType    : chr "ANY"
      .. .. .. ..@ elementMetadata: NULL
      .. .. .. ..@ metadata       : list()
      .. ..@ rowRanges          :Formal class 'GRangesList' [package "GenomicRanges"] with 5 slots
      .. .. .. ..@ unlistData     :Formal class 'GRanges' [package "GenomicRanges"] with 6 slots
      .. .. .. .. .. ..@ seqnames       :Formal class 'Rle' [package "S4Vectors"] with 4 slots
      .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ values         : Factor w/ 0 levels: 
      .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ lengths        : int(0) 
      .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ elementMetadata: NULL
      .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ metadata       : list()
      .. .. .. .. .. ..@ ranges         :Formal class 'IRanges' [package "IRanges"] with 6 slots
      .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ start          : int(0) 
      .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ width          : int(0) 
      .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ NAMES          : NULL
      .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ elementType    : chr "integer"
      .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ elementMetadata: NULL
      .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ metadata       : list()
      .. .. .. .. .. ..@ strand         :Formal class 'Rle' [package "S4Vectors"] with 4 slots
      .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ values         : Factor w/ 3 levels "+","-","*": 
      .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ lengths        : int(0) 
      .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ elementMetadata: NULL
      .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ metadata       : list()
      .. .. .. .. .. ..@ elementMetadata:Formal class 'DataFrame' [package "S4Vectors"] with 6 slots
      .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ rownames       : NULL
      .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ nrows          : int 0
      .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ listData       : Named list()
      .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ elementType    : chr "ANY"
      .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ elementMetadata: NULL
      .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ metadata       : list()
      .. .. .. .. .. ..@ seqinfo        :Formal class 'Seqinfo' [package "GenomeInfoDb"] with 4 slots
      .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ seqnames   : chr(0) 
      .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ seqlengths : int(0) 
      .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ is_circular: logi(0) 
      .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ genome     : chr(0) 
      .. .. .. .. .. ..@ metadata       : list()
      .. .. .. ..@ elementMetadata:Formal class 'DataFrame' [package "S4Vectors"] with 6 slots
      .. .. .. .. .. ..@ rownames       : NULL
      .. .. .. .. .. ..@ nrows          : int 33694
      .. .. .. .. .. ..@ listData       :List of 11
      .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ id                   : chr [1:33694] "ENSG00000243485" "ENSG00000237613" "ENSG00000186092" "ENSG00000238009" ...
      .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ symbol               : chr [1:33694] "RP11-34P13.3" "FAM138A" "OR4F5" "RP11-34P13.7" ...
      .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ is_feature_control   : logi [1:33694] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
      .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ is_feature_control_MT: logi [1:33694] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
      .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ mean_counts          : num [1:33694] 0 0 0 0.000895 0.000179 ...
      .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ log10_mean_counts    : num [1:33694] 0.00 0.00 0.00 3.89e-04 7.77e-05 ...
      .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ rank_counts          : num [1:33694] 6741 6741 6741 18054 14520 ...
      .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ n_cells_counts       : int [1:33694] 0 0 0 5 1 0 0 0 611 542 ...
      .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ pct_dropout_counts   : num [1:33694] 100 100 100 99.9 100 ...
      .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ total_counts         : num [1:33694] 0 0 0 5 1 0 0 0 661 617 ...
      .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ log10_total_counts   : num [1:33694] 0 0 0 0.778 0.301 ...
      .. .. .. .. .. ..@ elementType    : chr "ANY"
      .. .. .. .. .. ..@ elementMetadata: NULL
      .. .. .. .. .. ..@ metadata       : list()
      .. .. .. ..@ partitioning   :Formal class 'PartitioningByEnd' [package "IRanges"] with 5 slots
      .. .. .. .. .. ..@ end            : int [1:33694] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
      .. .. .. .. .. ..@ NAMES          : chr [1:33694] "ENSG00000243485" "ENSG00000237613" "ENSG00000186092" "ENSG00000238009" ...
      .. .. .. .. .. ..@ elementType    : chr "integer"
      .. .. .. .. .. ..@ elementMetadata: NULL
      .. .. .. .. .. ..@ metadata       : list()
      .. .. .. ..@ elementType    : chr "GRanges"
      .. .. .. ..@ metadata       : list()
      .. ..@ colData            :Formal class 'DataFrame' [package "S4Vectors"] with 6 slots
      .. .. .. ..@ rownames       : chr [1:5586] "AAACCTGAGAAGGTTT-1" "AAACCTGAGCGTTCCG-1" "AAACCTGAGTACGTAA-1" "AAACCTGGTAAACACA-1" ...
      .. .. .. ..@ nrows          : int 5586
      .. .. .. ..@ listData       :List of 30
      .. .. .. .. ..$ dataset                               : int [1:5586] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ barcode                               : chr [1:5586] "AAACCTGAGAAGGTTT-1" "AAACCTGAGCGTTCCG-1" "AAACCTGAGTACGTAA-1" "AAACCTGGTAAACACA-1" ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ total_features                        : int [1:5586] 1373 1837 2259 802 2601 1967 1236 1642 1153 1078 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ log10_total_features                  : num [1:5586] 3.14 3.26 3.35 2.9 3.42 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ total_counts                          : num [1:5586] 3380 7332 10099 1833 12184 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ log10_total_counts                    : num [1:5586] 3.53 3.87 4 3.26 4.09 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ pct_counts_top_50_features            : num [1:5586] 33.1 38.9 42.5 40.9 42.2 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ pct_counts_top_100_features           : num [1:5586] 45 54.8 59.2 53.7 53.5 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ pct_counts_top_200_features           : num [1:5586] 57.5 66.9 69 66.4 64.7 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ pct_counts_top_500_features           : num [1:5586] 74.2 79.2 79.4 83.5 76.8 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ total_features_endogenous             : int [1:5586] 1373 1837 2259 802 2601 1967 1236 1642 1153 1078 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ log10_total_features_endogenous       : num [1:5586] 3.14 3.26 3.35 2.9 3.42 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ total_counts_endogenous               : num [1:5586] 3380 7332 10099 1833 12184 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ log10_total_counts_endogenous         : num [1:5586] 3.53 3.87 4 3.26 4.09 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ pct_counts_endogenous                 : num [1:5586] 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ pct_counts_top_50_features_endogenous : num [1:5586] 33.1 38.9 42.5 40.9 42.2 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ pct_counts_top_100_features_endogenous: num [1:5586] 45 54.8 59.2 53.7 53.5 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ pct_counts_top_200_features_endogenous: num [1:5586] 57.5 66.9 69 66.4 64.7 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ pct_counts_top_500_features_endogenous: num [1:5586] 74.2 79.2 79.4 83.5 76.8 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ total_features_feature_control        : int [1:5586] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ log10_total_features_feature_control  : num [1:5586] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ total_counts_feature_control          : num [1:5586] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ log10_total_counts_feature_control    : num [1:5586] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ pct_counts_feature_control            : num [1:5586] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ total_features_MT                     : int [1:5586] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ log10_total_features_MT               : num [1:5586] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ total_counts_MT                       : num [1:5586] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ log10_total_counts_MT                 : num [1:5586] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ pct_counts_MT                         : num [1:5586] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
      .. .. .. .. ..$ is_cell_control                       : logi [1:5586] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
      .. .. .. ..@ elementType    : chr "ANY"
      .. .. .. ..@ elementMetadata: NULL
      .. .. .. ..@ metadata       : list()
      .. ..@ assays             :Reference class 'ShallowSimpleListAssays' [package "SummarizedExperiment"] with 1 field
      .. .. ..$ data: NULL
      .. .. ..and 14 methods.
      .. ..@ NAMES              : NULL
      .. ..@ elementMetadata    :Formal class 'DataFrame' [package "S4Vectors"] with 6 slots
      .. .. .. ..@ rownames       : NULL
      .. .. .. ..@ nrows          : int 33694
      .. .. .. ..@ listData       : Named list()
      .. .. .. ..@ elementType    : chr "ANY"
      .. .. .. ..@ elementMetadata: NULL
      .. .. .. ..@ metadata       : list()
      .. ..@ metadata           :List of 1
      .. .. ..$ name: chr "iMates-1"




Here is one of the four objects.
```

Could anyone of you help me.

Thank you

Comment: are you sure your sc_list contains anything? I'm not sure `mget` works that way...

Comment: It is not empty.

Comment: Please put the additional information about `str(sc_list)` from the comment in your question, i.e. **edit your question:** https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53434082/edit

Comment: @jogo edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: The object `sc_list` is a list of S4-objects. The components of a S4-object are slots. The operator to access a slot is `@` (not `$`).

Comment: @jogo: thank you for the suggestion. I did replace $ with @ still the same error

Comment: Is `UE <- lapply(sc_list, cF, 2500, 1000, 5)` acceptable for you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `sc_list` is a list of lists, right?
If so, can you check if the following code works?

```
sc_list=mget(sc)
for (i in 1:5)
sc_list[[i]]$ue <- cF(sc_list[[i]], 2500, 1000, 5)
```

Comment: I got this error now. "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Comment: can you post the output of `str(sc_list)`?

Comment: it is a very big output. But what I can see is that it starts with " List of 4". I hope this is what you were trying to confirm. The first line is like sc_1:Formal class 'SingleCellExperiment' [package "SingleCellExperiment"] with 10 slots
  .. ..@ int_elementMetadata:Formal class 'DataFrame' [package "S4Vectors"] with 6 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ rownames       : NULL
  .. .. .. ..@ nrows          : int 22496
  .. .. .. ..@ listData       :List of 2

Comment: So it is a list of S4-objects.

Comment: @jogo: Yes, indeed. How should I fix this.

Comment: can you also post the output of `str(sc_1)`?